# R: plot 3d interaction model and observations using plotly

Tags: r, regression, plotly

I start from a simple interaction model `z = 0.5*x*y`. The goal is to plot simulated observations with `add_markers()` as well as the model with `add_surface()` using the `plotly` library.

So far I have manage to simulate the data and plot it:

```
library(plotly)
library(magrittr)

x <- rnorm(10000)
y <- rnorm(10000)
z <- 0.5 * x * y

plot_ly() %>% add_markers(x = x, y = y, z = z, marker = list(size = 1))
```

This is what the plot looks like:
[image]

I then tried to surface plot the model:

```
plot_ly() %>% 
   add_markers(x = x, y = y, z = z, marker = list(size = 1)) %>%
   add_surface(z = matrix(z, 100, 100))
```

But it produces something completely different to what it would be expected. This is approximately the result that would be expect from the surface plot:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to regress your values on the coordinate system to recover the mathematical relationship. Beware that the lack of any error in this dataset may cause difficulties with some regression implementations if the matrix operation run into problems with invertibility.

Comment: @42- Would you mind posting your answer with the code as I am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy workaround is to use:

```
plot_ly(x = x, y = y, z= z, type = 'mesh3d')
```

[image]

Or using surface plot:

```
  library(tidyverse)
  grid <- expand.grid(x = seq(from = -3, to = 3, length.out = 100),
                      y = seq(from = -3, to = 3, length.out = 100))

  grid %>%
    mutate(z = 0.5 * x * y) %>%
    spread(key = y, value = z) %>%
    as.matrix() -> z


  plot_ly() %>%
    add_surface(z = z, x = unique(grid$x), y = unique(grid$y)) %>%
    layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(range = c(-2.5, 2.5)),
                        yaxis = list(range = c(-2.5, 2.5)))) #odd artifact if all values are plotted - check without layout call
```

or:

```
model = lm(z ~ x * y)

grid <- expand.grid(x = seq(from = -3, to = 3, length.out = 100),
                      y = seq(from = -3, to = 3, length.out = 100))

grid$z = predict(model, grid)
```

and proceed as above

```
 grid %>%       
    spread(key = y, value = z) %>%
    as.matrix() -> z
```

[image]

Comment: It is indeed very close to what I'm looking for, but it is not exactly the (theoretical) model. I will accept your response if no one else provides a better answer.

Comment: In this case you mapped the data. What I need is a map of the predictions made by the model, which would look like the picture I posted. There should be some error between the observed data and the predictions.

Comment: The one stated above: `z = 0.5*x*y`. Basically, `data = model + error`.